# save responses of a selenium page request to file

Tags: python, selenium

Is there a way to save to get responses in the network tab when I open a page in selenium for example when I open Google exactly 6 GET and 3 POST are made, What I want to do is to save responses for each GET in a file.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://google.com') # in network tab many GET are made
```

Comment: not sure if selenium has such capabilities, but did you try some network sniffers? such as Wireshark ?

Comment: Wireshark is the wrong tool for this. Something like browsermob maybe.

Comment: @pguardiario can you further explain on how browsermob can be used to do this

Comment: @BohdanKaminskyi Wireshark is a way to do this, but is on a different planet of what I want to do

Comment: Any mitm-style proxy will work (I use anyproxy sometimes), you will probably need to install a certificate or else run with --disable-web-security

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible using the Selenium WebDriver API. This has been discussed in the issue [tracker](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/141) for the project, and the feature will not be added to the API.

If you want , you have to use outside of selenium like request module in py

Comment: Is there any other way ?

Comment: Amended on  answer.